# Nautilus menu dissapeared

Tags: 12.10, globalmenu

I did fresh install Ubuntu 12.10 64,

I found that my nautilus menu (File, Edit, View) is suddenly disappeared whenever I want to click on it. But it will showed up whenever I hovered my mouse somewhere else (center-to-right of global menu bar)

anyone experience the same issue?

picture added:

[image: Global Menu nautilus gone]

For example, if I want to click (left area of global menu)"Edit" that appeared next to "Home Folder" it suddenly disappeared!

However, if I click somewhere in the center-to-right of global menu, the menu suddenly re-appeared.

[image: Global Menu nautilus re-appeared]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is what you are experiencing in your desktop upper part is not panel.......When you open any of your nautilus then it automatically convert your folder's status bar......If you put your cursor over there then it appears......Instead of going every time with cursor there use these shortcuts....

View----Alt+V

Edit----Alt+E

Help----Alt+H

Comment: Thanks for your advice on shortcut, it solved part of my problem. but still. whenever I want to click edit or view.. they're gone